# Can't RDP on Windows Storage Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

We have a Windows Storage Server 2012 and I'm not able to open RDP connection to it, I get two different error messages randomly (attached).

[image]

[image]

I'm able to ping the server (attached)

[image]

I'm able to open telnet on RDP port (attached)

[image]

Any suggestions, please? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's being logged in the event log on the server? Have you tried restarting it (or at least the Remote Desktop Services service)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after force restart on the server. Gotta work on RCA now, thanks.